# Publish Website made from R in Github

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, web-deployment

I created a website (html file) using the `rmarkdown::rendersite()` function in R. It works really well but it is just an html file.

How do I deploy this to github or another public server for me to make a publicly accessed url out of this?

My current github repository is here: https://github.com/nknauer/first_website

So far, I created a repository on github and followed the tutorial available [here](http://nickstrayer.me/RMarkdown_Sites_tutorial/). However, I still couldn't make it into a webpage.

I guess the main question I'm asking is: **has anyone tried [this tutorial](http://nickstrayer.me/RMarkdown_Sites_tutorial/) and successfully deployed a webpage (not just an html file) through github** and **are there other ways to do this from Rmarkdown?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, here is one way:

1. Create a html file
2. Create `docs/` directory
3. Go to settings and enable the `docs/` directory.
4. Place the file there in `docs/`. You are done.

One example is eg [this web page](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/rcppapt/binnmuAfterR340.html) corresponding to [this file](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppapt/blob/master/docs/binnmuAfterR340.html) based on this [vignette directory](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppapt/tree/master/vignettes).

Moving the files around is simple too; you could use Travis or other means.  An older approach used a separate branch `gh-pages`, but the current form is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I was also able to get it to work from the tutorial also now. There were a few tweeks made such as instead of "git push origin master" just change to "git push". Also need to make another folder within the "personal_site" folder on your personal computer to act as a master branch.